# What is the alternative to "select for update" in subquery in postgresql 8.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to atomically update a row in based on the results of a subquery in PostgreSQL 8.4. In PostgreSQL 9.2 this worked well:

```
UPDATE item SET status = 1 WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT id FROM item WHERE status = 3 LIMIT(1) FOR UPDATE) RETURNING ID;
```

But on PostgreSQL 8.4 I am the following error message:

```
ERROR: SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries
```

What would be a good substitute on 8.4?

Comment: As per Denis's answer, remove the words, "for update".  You also have a logic problem in that you are using the limit keyword without an order by clause.  That means you might not be updating the row you intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to select for update. It is done automatically in your query.

Comment: That seemed to work well, Denis.. Sometimes the solution is staring you in the face!